# Python indentation semantics

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, indentation

I just have a very simple question, and just need to confirm that I got the point.

Say that we have the following Python code snippet:

```
x = 0
if x == 5:
    print 'x is equal to 5'
else:
    print 'x is not equal to 5'

print 'program done'
```

If we indent the statement `print 'program done'` as follows:

```
else:
    print 'x is not equal to 5'
    print 'program done'
```

Will `print 'program done'` in this case be part of the block code associated with `else`?

Comment: indentation in python is very similar to the use of braces to mark scoping in languages like c and perl.  It is also the equivalent of end statements in ruby.

Comment: "try it and see" is a great way to answer questions like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation):

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

So, yeah, it will belong to the `else` block.